# How to substract 2 datetime list in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have 2 different columns in an excel (which I have imported using pandas in Python) as below

```
data['issue created'] = ['12/31/2015 11:59:45 PM', '12/31/2015 11:59:44 PM', '12/31/2015 11:59:29 PM', '12/31/2015 11:59:29 PM']

data['issue closed']= ['12/31/2015 11:57:46 PM', '12/31/2015 11:56:58 PM', '12/31/2015 11:56:30 PM', '12/31/2015 11:55:32 PM']
```

How I can substract these 2 columns to get the new column which gives me the elapsed time?

```
data['elapsed duration'] = data['issue closed'] - data['issue created']
```

Comment: Why does closing happen before creating?

Comment: ahh, good observation, I just took an example with some random number, but intention was to understand how to subtract 2 datetime columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the columns into a `datetime` type. They are probably an `object` type right now (essentially a string in pandas).

```py
data['issue created'] = pd.to_datetime(data['issue created'])
data['issue closed'] = pd.to_datetime(data['issue closed'])
```

This will then let you subtract them into a new column just like you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your date columns to real dates first:

```
df['issue created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue created'])
df['issue closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue closed'])

df['elapsed time'] = df['issue created'] - df['issue closed']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        issue created        issue closed    elapsed time
0 2015-12-31 23:59:45 2015-12-31 23:57:46 0 days 00:01:59
1 2015-12-31 23:59:44 2015-12-31 23:56:58 0 days 00:02:46
2 2015-12-31 23:59:29 2015-12-31 23:56:30 0 days 00:02:59
3 2015-12-31 23:59:29 2015-12-31 23:55:32 0 days 00:03:57
```